# Rspec: test if method was called on an object inside a job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rails-activejob

I made a job to call a method if `ended_at` was less than today. For some reason I keep getting failures even if I throw a binding pry right at the moment it is about to break and manually call the method and it works fine. However, I still get a failure if I just let the spec test run on its own.

My job:

```
class RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform

    old_events = Event.where("ended_at < ?", Date.today)
    old_events.each do |e|
      e.remove_from_algolia
    end
  end
end
```

My method:

```
def remove_from_algolia
  index = Algolia::Index.new(@@ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME)
  index.delete_object(self.id)
end
```

My spec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob, type: :job do
    it "will remove old events from the index" do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    event = FactoryGirl.create(:event, title: "EXPIRED EVENT", ended_at: 1.day.ago)

    RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob.perform_now

    expect(event).to receive(:remove_from_algolia)
  end
end
```

RSpec output:

```
Failures:

  1) d will remove old events from the index
     Failure/Error: expect(event).to receive(:remove_from_algolia)

       (#<Event id: 401, uuid: "6e9a6f08-c34d-45af-9f3c-870b28643809", organization_id: nil, event_type_id: nil, name: "cool-event", title: "Cool Event", description: "Rad thing that's gonna happen", platform_type: "ee", platform_id: "12345678", platform_url: "http://event.com/12345678", featured: false, capacity: 100, rsvp_count: nil, attendee_count: nil, status: "upcoming", started_at: "2017-10-21 03:00:39", ended_at: "2017-03-23 07:00:00", deleted_at: "2017-10-21 03:00:39", created_at: "2017-03-24 00:24:54", updated_at: "2017-03-24 00:24:54", location_line_1: nil, location_line_2: nil, location_city: nil, location_state: nil, location_zip: nil, location_country: nil>).remove_from_algolia(*(any args))
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments
     # ./spec/jobs/remove_old_events_from_algolia_job_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.8828 seconds (files took 7.12 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/jobs/remove_old_events_from_algolia_job_spec.rb:4 # RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob will remove old events from the index

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /workproject/coverage. 384 / 496 LOC (77.42%) covered.
```

I can put a `binding.pry` inside my job during the spec test and call that method successfully:

```
     4: def perform
     5:
     6:   old_events = Event.where("ended_at < ?", Date.today)
     7:   old_events.each do |e|
 =>  8:   binding.pry
     9:     e.remove_from_algolia
    10:   end
    11: end

[1] pry(#<RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob>)> e.remove_from_algolia
=> {"deletedAt"=>"2017-03-24T00:37:53.743Z", "taskID"=>206043962, "objectID"=>"409"}
[2] pry(#<RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob>)>
```

Comment: when you call the method manually, does the test pass or still fail?

Comment: It still fails once I manually call it and then exit `pry`. However, I know I'm in the loop where I intend to be so I don't know why I don't pass. I'm going to assume it works but the test itself is broken. I though this was the correct way to test if a method was called on an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a stub for `event` instead of a real `Event` model:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob, type: :job do
    it "will remove old events from the index" do
    ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :test
    event = double('event')
    allow(Event).to receive(:where).and_return([event])
    expect(event).to receive(:remove_from_algolia)

    RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob.perform_now

  end
end
```

Comment: I haven't done an RSpec mock before. Can you parse this failure after trying your method?

` 1) RemoveOldEventsFromAlgoliaJob will remove old events from the index`
     `Failure/Error: e.remove_from_algolia`
       `#<Double "event"> received unexpected message` `:remove_from_algolia with (no args)`

Comment: move the last expect before calling the job, see updated code

Comment: That works. Do you have an explaination why this works but the other way does? I was stuck on this for a while and haven't come across this solution.

Comment: RSpec cannot "record" what is happening on a given object unless it is created by RSpec itself

Comment: Makes sense. I do question the fact that I'm not really testing the job (in the fact that it only calls on events that are older than today. Rather, it seems I'm just testing my ability to see if the object can receive the method at all.

Comment: Yes right. this is proper unit testing. You are stubbing all the dependencies. You need a separate test for `Event` to test what `remove_from_algolia` does

Comment: I'm not trying to test what the method does. I just want to test if the job will execute on old events and not on events that happen today or in the future.