# Rails Job loses reference to module randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activejob

**EDIT: same things happens when I fork a process manually...**
I'm getting some weird behavior with a Rails Job that calls a module of mine called `RedisService`.
I've added `lib/modules` to my `autoload_paths` but the `TextService` module that calls the `RedisService` one loses reference to it, sometimes immediately, sometimes 3 or 4 job calls in...
I've even required the module in my TextService to no avail, even added some puts to check that always show the module is defined and responds to the method I'm calling...!
Something escapes me...
[Here's a gist to the backtrace](https://gist.github.com/thomasbromehead/1b2a62d93334d1c4e0d3a8939338203c)
Repo: https://gitlab.com/thomasbromehead/snmp-simulator-ruby-manager.
`ruby --version: 2.6.5`
`rails version: 6.1.3.1`

My "service" objects:
**Module that calls RedisService**

```rb
require_relative 'redis_service'

module TextService
  def self.write_to_file(dataObject, redis, path: "./")
    begin
      file_with_path = path + dataObject.filename
      # Store all lines prior to the one being modified, File.read closes the file
      f = File.read(file_with_path)
      new_content = f.gsub(dataObject.old_set_value, dataObject.new_set_value)
      # File.open closes the file when passed a block
      File.open(file_with_path, "w") { |file| file.puts new_content }
      puts "Redis is: #{redis}"                                    ======> RedisService
      puts "Redis responds to multi: #{redis.respond_to?(:multi)}" ======> true
      redis.multi do
        redis.zrem("#{dataObject.name}-sorted-set", dataObject.old_set_value)
        redis.hset("#{dataObject.name}-offsets", "#{dataObject.start_index}:#{dataObject.oid}:#{dataObject.end_index}", dataObject.new_set_value)
        redis.zadd("#{dataObject.name}-sorted-set", dataObject.start_index, dataObject.new_set_value)
      end
    rescue EOFError
    end
  end
```

**Variation class called from VariateJob**

```rb
require_relative '../../../lib/modules/redis_service'

module Snmp
  class Variation
    include ActiveModel::Model

    attr_reader :oid, :type, :duration, :to, :from, :filename, :redis

    def initialize(oid:nil, duration:nil, type:nil, to:nil, filename: nil, from:nil)
      @to = to
      @from = from
      @oid = oid
      @type = type
      @filename = filename
      @redis = RedisService
    end

    def run(data)
      current_value, new_set_value, start_index, end_index  = prepare_values(JSON.parse(data))
      transferData = Snmp::TransferData.new({
        filename: @filename,
        old_set_value: current_value,
        new_set_value: new_set_value,
        start_index: start_index,
        end_index: end_index,
        name: @name,
        oid: oid
      })
      TextService.write_to_file(transferData, @redis)
    end
```

**VariateJob**

```rb
class VariateJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
  def perform(dumped_variation, data)
    Marshal.load(dumped_variation).run(Marshal.load(data))
  end
end
```

**VariationsController**

```rb
class VariationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_file_name, only: :start

  def start
    if params["linear"]
      type = :linear
    elsif params["random"]
      type = :random
    end
    data = redis.hscan_each("#@name-offsets", match: "*:#{params["snmp_variation"]["oid"]}*")
    # data is an Enumerator, transform it to an array and dump to JSON
    variation = Snmp::Variation.new(params_to_keywords(params["snmp_variation"]).merge({type: type}))
    VariateJob.perform_later(Marshal.dump(variation), Marshal.dump(JSON.generate(data.to_a.first)))
  end
```

**RedisService**

```rb
require 'redis'

module RedisService
  include GlobalID::Identification

[...]
  def self.multi(&block)
    @redis.multi { block.call() }
  end
[...]
end
```

Comment: How does your RedisService look like – especially this line: `/usr/src/snmpapp/lib/modules/redis_service.rb:102:in `multi'`? Because to me, it looks like the error is actually in the RedisService in that line. Is it possible that you call `multi` in that line too?

Comment: Hi @spickermann,
I've added a snippet of the RedisService.
I deleted the redis.multi wrapper and get the same error with `redis.zrem` even though RedisService is defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not losing the reference to the RedisService, but to Redis in your RedisService. Probably because you use a server or worker that forks new processes and you don't initialize a new connection after the fork.

To fix this issue I would replace this method

```
def self.start(host,port)
  @redis ||= Redis.new(host: host, port: port)
  self
end
```

with

```
def self.redis
  @redis ||= Redis.new(host: ::Snmpapp.redis_config[:host], port: ::Snmpapp.redis_config[:port])
end
```

And then I would replace all call to the `@redis` with a `redis` call to the new method.

Comment: Hi @spickermann,
Thanks A LOT, I'm not used to jobs and it makes sense that because processes don't share memory with their parent process I lose the connection to my redis container. 
Really appreciate you taking the time to dig into the code in my gitlab as well, means a lot to a junior like me.
I'd be happy to send you some Basic Attention Token to a pubkey if you want.
Vielen danke

Comment: Thanks a lot. But you do not need to send me any tokens. I am happy to answer questions for StackOverflow reputation points. ;-)

Comment: Haha, good spirit ;) If you want some more feel free to take a look at this other question I posted here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989462/rspec-test-if-method-was-called-on-an-object-inside-a-job/66951332#66951332

Comment: Looks like you posted the new question as an answer to another question. That is not how it should be done on StackOverflow and your question will probably be deleted soon for that reason. Just ask a new question instead.